# Upgrading d3 doesn't show up x axis ticks labels any more. Bug?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

A few months ago, I made a graphic istogram using d3, and was a 3.3.1 version.
Now I upgraded to the last version (3.4.1).
But from that moment the x axis labels don't show up any more (only the first one).   Is it a bug or I have to upgrade my code in some way?       here is my code:
     `//Define X axis 
     xAxisBigG = d3.svg.axis()
     .scale(xScaleBigG)
     .orient("bottom")
     .tickValues(nomi_reg_original)
     .ticks(nomi_reg_original.length);
    svgBigG.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis") 
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + (hBigG -( y_nomi_x_asse) )+ ")")
    .call(xAxisBigG)
    .selectAll("text")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("dx", "-.8em")
    .attr("dy", "-.25em") 
    .attr("transform", function (d) {return "rotate(-65)";});`
and here you can see the results of the same code with the different version of d3    [with version 3.3.1](http://www.mudaedizioni.it/proveGeo/prototipi/3/map/monographic_version3.html)  and
[with version 3.4.1](http://www.mudaedizioni.it/proveGeo/prototipi/3/map/monographic_version34.html)

Comment: Could be this change in 3.3.6 "Fix d3.svg.axis to not pollute an ordinal scale’s domain when an explicit range is used." Try setting only `tickValues` and not `ticks` on the axis.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff: I checked all versions: this problem starts with the 3.3.4 version (labels appear but in a wrong position (the middle of the graph), in 3.3.4 labels disappear. If I don't set `ticks` nothing changes.